# White line spaces in xml while using the File Stream

Tags: c#

I'm having an XML which will look like following

```
<root>
    <node>
        <a1>text</a1>
        <a2>text</a2>
        <a3></a3>
    </node>
</root>
```

If i loaded this in a xmldocument and saved it. The xml becomes following

```
<root>
    <node>
        <a1>text</a1>
        <a2>text</a2>
        <a3>
        </a3>
    </node>
</root>
```

My code snippet:

```
 public static Void Update(String Path)
        {
            FileStream docIn = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(Path);
            XmlNodeList nodeY = xml.SelectNodes("/root/node/a1");
            _count = 0;
            foreach (XmlNode live in nodeY)
            {
              //changing nodeY InnerText
            }

            xml.Save(Path);

        }
```

I do not wish to use the preservewhitespace= true option since it makes my xml looks like this

```
<root><node><a1>text</a1><a2>text</a2><a3></a3></node></root>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You didn't say what the problem was ...?

Comment: Did you manipulate a3 in any way?  And what data type is xml?

Comment: Statin the problem would help - so far all 3 versions of XML are equialent and valid... BTW you aren't using preservewhitespace= true correctly if you loosing all whitespaces altogether.

Comment: The problem is i'm getting is a new line char in the a3 node. I am not manipulating anything with a3. The solution i need is to have the new line character removed inside the a3 node. I have updated the code snippet which provided previously to help you all to have a better understanding. Please let me know if you find any issue's.

Comment: By the way, this local variable is un-used: `FileStream docIn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify `XmlWriter` settings explicitly using an instance `XmlWriterSettings` class.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        Indent = true,
        NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false
    };

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outXmlPath, settings))
{
    xml.Save(writer);
}
```

Hope this helps.